# zsh fc does not open editor properly

Tags: zsh

If I understand the fc docu correctly, an 'fc -1' should open the editor with the last command in it, and which I can edit and then execute by leaving the editor. But what happens for me is that the command is executed immediately, and the editor (vi) opens emptily. If I close the editor  nothing happens.

Any idea what could cause this? I have nothing special installed as far as I know. The history shows properly on 'fc -l'.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found this behavior relates to the editor. My EDITOR environment variable was set to vi which was an alias to gvim. If I set the EDITOR to /usr/bin/vi explicitly, the basic vi editor pops up with the command in it, as expected.